# Page stops loading when reaches <?php echo get_fbimage(); ?> - No solution

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress, facebook-opengraph

I am being facing this problem since the last 8 hours, my nose is almost on the keyboard...
I started searching for a solution to put a code on the header.php of my Wordpress for facebook og:image.
It seems simple BUT the page always stop loading when reaching the line of code so it is always a white page without any information.

Page stops loading when reaches `<?php echo get_fbimage(); ?>` - No solution

Here is the line: `<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo get_fbimage(); ?>"/>`

1- If I remove that line or the `<?php echo get_fbimage(); ?>`, everything goes well...

2- Even without the function get_fbimage() on functions.php, it doesn't work.

Here is the page online: http://www.contagiarte.pt/centroformacaocultural/formacao/formacao-fixa/yoga/

I need to get a solution to fix this or alternative solution for getting Facebook pulling the correct image of each wordpress page.
Thank's in advance.

Here goes the first part of header.php code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/"
xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">

<title><?php if (is_home()) { ?><?php bloginfo('name'); ?> - <?php bloginfo('description'); ?><?php } else { ?><?php wp_title($sep = ''); ?> - <?php bloginfo('name'); ?><?php } ?></title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="<?php bloginfo('html_type') ?>; charset=<?php bloginfo('charset') ?>" />






<!-- Facebook Open Graph -->
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="155171734506350" />
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php the_title(); ?>"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php
  if ( function_exists('wpseo_get_value') ) {
    echo wpseo_get_value('metadesc');
  } else {
    echo $post->post_excerpt;
  }
?>"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="<?php
  if (is_single() || is_page()) { echo "article"; } else { echo "website";}
?>"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>"/>



<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo get_fbimage(); ?>"/>




<meta name="description" content="<?php bloginfo('description') ?>" />
<?php if(is_search()) { ?>
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" /> 
<?php }?>
```

Comment: I assume no PHP errors are being generated? either in logs or with error reporting configuration items.

Comment: The problem is not 'get_get_fbimage()', I will get the same white page if I write '<?php echo somethingasdsfg(); ?>'
I just know that is that the line is causing the mistake because if you open the source code it stops right there...

There is nothing on the error log to help me figure out what can be causing this...!

Comment: Why are you hard coding this? Your "Fix Facebook Like WordPress Plugin" is generating all the needed metadata on lines 83-90 of your source. Adding the metadata a second time will cause an error.

Comment: Also, have you tried setting `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` in `wp-config.php` to see if this gives you any insight?

Comment: @cpilko I was trying that plugin "Fix Facebook...." when you saw the source. But it didn't work. I am still getting that same problem, it stops when reading that line...
But thanks to your advice to put WP_DEBUG on I found the following errors:

Comment: @cpilko
Notice: Undefined index: aioseop_migrate in /home1/hugolima/public_html/contagiarte/centroformacaocultural/wp-content/plugins/all-in-one-seo-pack/all_in_one_seo_pack.php on line 536

Notice: Undefined index: aioseop_migrate_options in /home1/hugolima/public_html/contagiarte/centroformacaocultural/wp-content/plugins/all-in-one-seo-pack/all_in_one_seo_pack.php on line 537

Notice: Undefined index: aiosp_enabled in /home1/hugolima/public_html/contagiarte/centroformacaocultural/wp-content/plugins/all-in-one-seo-pack/all_in_one_seo_pack.php on line 657

Comment: So I went to that file and
on line 536: if($_POST['aioseop_migrate']) aioseop_mrt_fix_meta();
on line 537: if($_POST['aioseop_migrate_options']) aioseop_mrt_mkarry();
on line 657: if( ($_POST['aiosp_enabled'] == null && $aioseop_options['aiosp_enabled']!='1') || $_POST['aiosp_enabled']=='0'){
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'aioseop_activation_notice');
}

And that's all... I don't find the solution... but it already help your advice. Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: You can ignore those warnings. Make sure you set `define('WP_DEBUG', false);` again.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it’s because the page is not loading the `functions.php` that you mention?

So maybe change this:

```
<?php echo get_fbimage(); ?>
```

To this this:

```
<?php echo require_once('functions.php'); get_fbimage(); ?>
```

I am assuming that the `functions.php` is in the same folder as this page?  If not then you need to set that `require_once` to point to the location of `functions.php`

Comment: Thanks for the answer but no, it's not related to functions.php
That file is being loaded, there is other functions there that works correctly.
If I remove that line, everything is fine... it hangs when reaches that '<?php echo get_fbimage(); ?>'